# Rewrite with definitional equality and dependent types

Tags: coq, dependent-type, equality, rewriting

In Coq, there are some terms that are equal by definition, but there's not an easy way to replace one value with the other inside a proof.  The two ways that I know that work in general are to use the `change` tactic (which can be cumbersome at times), and to make a lemma saying that the two things are equal and then using `rewrite`.  However, the second approach can run into trouble with dependent types, as this example shows:

```ml
Definition a := O.

Theorem aO : a = O.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Theorem test : forall (S : nat -> Prop) (H : S O), ex_intro S O H = ex_intro S a H.
Proof.
  intros S H.
  rewrite aO. (* fails *)
Abort.
```

So, my question is, is there a way to do something like `rewrite` but that works in this situation?  Of course, I could use `change` (which is what I currently do), but sometimes the terms being converted are quite large and I would rather not have to type them out.

Edit: Since I've now received two answers that aren't what I'm looking for I thought I would clarify this: I'm not talking about simple situations like in the example where it's just a single definition.  I only provided the example to clarify what the fundamental issue is.  What I'm asking is, given arbitrary, complicated terms A and B such that `change A with B` works, how can I get around having to write out `A` and `B` every time?  Without dependent types I can just use a theorem `A = B` but I don't know of a way to do it with dependent types.

Comment: What about `simpl`?

Comment: Also, does `rewrite aO in *` work, if this extra lemma is acceptable?

Comment: Just a remark, but maybe you know this already: you do not always need to spell out the source of `change` in full: you only need to give a pattern that matches what you want to `change` in the target.

Comment: @mudri: `simpl` can only do certain conversions, and it sometimes does too much or too little.  `rewrite aO in *` doesn't work at all (Coq just says "nothing to rewrite").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I should have thought of this more before asking, but I thought of a solution that's at least better than everything I've thought of so far:

```ml
Definition a := O.

Theorem aO : a = O.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Ltac def_rewrite H := match type of H with | ?a = ?b => change a with b end.

Theorem test : forall (S : nat -> Prop) (H : S O), ex_intro S O H = ex_intro S a H.
Proof.
  intros S H.
  def_rewrite aO.
Abort.
```

However, this solution is not quite as versatile as `rewrite` is because `rewrite` can take theorems with parameters and work them out whereas `def_rewrite` has to take in a theorem with just the form `a = b`.  I'll wait to accept this as the answer in case anybody else can think of a better solution.

Comment: Not an answer but it seems likely  to extend this using ltac: apply the theorem to evars, (optionally, unify the LHS against arbitrary subterms using `match goal` and `context`), then change with the RHS.

Comment: @Blaisorblade I'm not that great with ltac, could you expand on that?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```ml
Theorem test : forall (S : nat -> Prop) (H : S O), ex_intro S O H = ex_intro S a H.
Proof.
  intros S H.
  change a with O.
Abort.
```

Is this what you need? See [the docs](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html#coq:tacn.change). It might be better if you say exactly when you find `change` cumbersome in the question.

Comment: I already mentioned this in the last paragraph of my question: sometimes the terms being converted are quite large and I would rather not have to type them out.

Comment: @sudgy So it would not be a `Definition`, but some arbitrary term in need of changing to some other arbitrary term, right? I don't see how you could provide these two terms apart from writing them out... I mean, how should Coq figure out which two terms to rewrite, if you don't write them out, at least somewhere?

Comment: `rewrite` with a separate theorem figures it out what I want to do just fine.  It just doesn't work with dependent types.

Comment: @sudgy But you still need to write out what you want to rewrite for `rewrite` as a theorem. So do you mean you want the ability for Coq to correctly instantiate a theorem for you?

Comment: Maybe you should give a real life example for what you want to rewrite, then it is more clear what your actual need is.

Comment: I feel like my real life examples are way too complicated to describe easily here (you can try searching through https://github.com/sudgy/math-from-nothing but honestly I would advise against it).  I'm fine with writing complicated things out in the statement of a theorem manually.  I just don't like huge `change`s in the middle of a proof.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssreflect:

```
Definition a := O.

Theorem test : forall (S : nat -> Prop) (H : S O), ex_intro S O H = ex_intro S a H.
Proof.
  intros S H.
  rewrite /a.
  rewrite -/a.
```

If you don't have ssreflect:

```
Definition a := O.

Theorem test : forall (S : nat -> Prop) (H : S O), ex_intro S O H = ex_intro S a H.
Proof.
  intros S H.
  unfold a.
  fold a.
```

Sometimes you have to type the terms out. In this case, use (for example) `rewrite -[O]/a.`

Comment: This doesn't work when the thing you are trying to change is not just a simple definition.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, if you have complicated expressions which aren't simple definitions, there's no way for Coq to guess which expression you want to change into which other expression, so you'll have to specify the expressions regardless. The "rewrite -[a]/b" syntax works whenever you specify the expressions.